# Youtube stops playing and beeps

Tags: youtube

I just installed Ubuntu on my old laptop, and after a few minuters watching youtube, the browser stops playing and beeps, I can use my computer and everithing but the video is stoped and the computer beeps.
I tryed Firefox, Opera, and Brave but its not the browser.
I also checked the temperature of the CPU and it was 64 so idk
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Intel(R) Atom(TM) x5-Z8350  CPU @ 1.44GHz

Comment: Intel "Bay Trail" CPUs family was always problematic with Linux, I suggest you google your exact CPU model + Ubuntu to get a feeling about it and, focusing on the newest results, try to apply some of the suggestions.

Comment: Exactly the same issue with Lubuntu (based on Ubuntu 22.04.1) on an Intel Atom Z3735F netbook.Sensor checks also show CPU temps are not critical (c 60C). This is presumably not related at all to the notorious C-state bugs in Bay Trail CPUs (because that causes hard crashes).

Comment: Since the sound gets lost (replaced by a continuous beep which ends when closing the browser tab) as the video (permanently) stalls, one would presume this is a sound issue.